# Create table based on data and relations

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to create a table based on data.
This data is simply an array with objects and each object has 3 properties (name, id, head).

- name: simply a name
- id: a unique ID
- head: the group above him, referenced to an ID from another group

**Example**

ID: 1
Name: Directie
Head: 1
*Basically the first group*

ID: 2
Name: Software
Head: 1
*Subgroup of Directie*

ID: 3
Name: Hardware
Head: 2
*Subgroup of Software*

And so on ...

Now I am trying to convert this into a table, but just cannot make it work. I can put the data in a table, but not in the correct order and place.

This is what I have so far. In my html I have an empty table and a filled table to check what the outcome would have to be.

**HTML**

```
<table id="chart">
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Directie</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Software</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Financieel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Hardware</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Studenten</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
var groepen = [];
var g1 = {name: "Directie", id: "1", head: "0"};
var g2 = {name: "Software", id:"2", head: "1"};
var g3 = {name: "Hardware", id:"3", head: "1"};
var g4 = {name: "Financieel", id:"4", head: "2"};
var g5 = {name: "Studenten", id: "5", head: "3"};
groepen = [g1,g2,g3,g4,g5];
var rows = groepen.length;
var columns = groepen[0].head;


for(var i = 1; i < groepen.length; i++)
{
    if(groepen[i].head > columns)
    {
        columns = groepen[i].head;   
    }
}

for(var row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    for(var cell = 0; cell < columns; cell++)
    {
        var td = $("<td></td>").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        tr.append(td);
    }
    $("#chart").append(tr);
}

for(var i = 0; i < groepen.length; i++)
{
    var row = $("#chart tbody tr:nth-child(" + groepen[i].id + ")").children("td:nth-child(" + groepen[i].head + ")").html(groepen[i].name);
}
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
```

If someone could help me out ... that would be great!

An example is seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/9zoq7qf1/) on jsFiddle

Comment: In your expected output why does Financieel render before Hardware?

Comment: because it is a subgroup of Software and I'm trying to create some sort of organizational chart. If you look at the groups I create in jsFiddle and when you compare the "id" with "head" each time, you will see the groups and subgroups, the order they come in and so on. I hope I am clear about what I want to achieve.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong,, You are ordering the main groups first and the sub groups after that, so Financieel being a main group renders before as Hardware is a sub-group

Comment: Yes, this is just a static arraylist. But the point will be retrieving this same list from a database. If there's any way to sort them in a good way, so it's easier to proces, feel free to point it out. I'm stuck with this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved.. but will have to add an extra parameter called level in the JSON for each entity representing the hierarchy

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/jxxhhxkf/1/

```
var groepen = [];
var g1 = {name: "Directie", id: "1", head: "0",level:0};
var g2 = {name: "Software", id:"2", head: "1",level:1};
var g3 = {name: "Hardware", id:"3", head: "1",level:1};
var g4 = {name: "Financieel", id:"4", head: "2",level:2};
var g5 = {name: "Studenten", id: "5", head: "3",level:2};
groepen = [g1,g2,g3,g4,g5];
var tree = [groepen[0]];
var groups = 0;
var level = 0;
function getChildren(id){
var isParent=false;
    for(var i=0;i<groepen.length;i++){
        if(groepen[i].head==id){
                tree.push(groepen[i])
                isParent = true;
                getChildren(groepen[i].id)
        }

}

if(isParent){
        groups++;
        return;
    }
}

getChildren(groepen[0].id);
var $table=$("<table></table>")
for(var i=0;i<tree.length;i++){
    var $tr =$("<tr></tr>");
for(var j=0;j<groups;j++){

    if(tree[i].level == j){
        $("<td>"+tree[i].name+"</td>").appendTo($tr);
    }
    else{
        $("<td></td>").appendTo($tr);
    }
}
$tr.appendTo($table)
}
$table.appendTo("body");
```

Comment: and is there a possibility to do this when the order of objects is different? e.g. [g23, g1, g2, g5, g4]? I don't know in what order I will call these objects from the database just yet. Even more, I'll have to find a way to add an extra "level" property. But thanks so far! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes this can be done.. groepen[0] was used as parameter for getChildren() function.. Instead of that we should search the groepen array and retrieve the element which has the least head value (I.e. 0) and then pass its ID to the getChildren() function.. The idea here is to pass the root element to get all its children..